# Is it possible to use virt-manager both for Openvz and KVM?

Tags: qemu, openvz

My code throws the error:

> Could not connect to libvirt.
>
> The end of the file was reached when reading the data: sh: nc: command not found: I / O error
>
> Make sure that the remote The node is running libvirtd.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [OpenVZ 7](https://openvz.org/Virt-manager_support_for_Virtuozzo_7), I do not believe it is possible with any other version of OpenVZ.

If you continue having issues, providing additional information such as your OpenVZ kernel version and how you arrived at the error you previously posted, would be helpful.